# geoip_record_by_name always returns null

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, geoip

I keep getting `null` when trying to use `geoip_record_by_name()` function.

I found GeoIP.dat files in `/usr/share/` dir and replaced them with extended dat files. [Here](https://ibb.co/8chJtn6) is my geoip extension phpinfo.

This code I use to test geoip:

```php
var_dump(geoip_record_by_name('111.111.111.111'));
```

Any suggestions about what may cause this problem?

Comment: did you try different IP or is this IP reachable from your system ?

Comment: Yes, i did. Always same result